# Conditionally wrap directive output in another directive

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to wrap the result of a directive in another directive, if a success condition is met.

For example:

`<greet name="mate">G'day</greet>`

becomes

`<highlight><greet name="mate">G'day</greet></highlight>`

if the *name* attribute of the *greet* directive is populated. Both directives are using transclusion.

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/h3nKvCkvJ8gjAOOYWsI8

Thoughts?

Comment: Will the attribute values be changing or will they be set once for each item only?

Comment: @charlietfl set initially for each item, not changing.

Comment: Seems over complicated then to me. Do you really need the outer to be a directive and not just use that span html? Also you don't need a link and a controller for each directive. Only really need a controller when you expect it to be `require`'d by child directives

Comment: @charlietfl this is a simple example, the real wrapping directive has a bunch of functionality for creating tooltips. I only want to wrap the tooltip directive if the inner directive has certain content.

Comment: well for starters would simply try creating a `<highlight>` element inside `greet` directive , using `angular.element`... append the greet element to it, compile and use replaceWith()